# using datefilter in if method django does not work

Tags: django, django-templates

dayone.inizio|date:"d" not working in if method.
how can i have only the data of the day in the form?
if I call it normally it works but inside the forloop it doesn't go it doesn't take me the day but the whole date.
From the views I can't because I also need other fields

```
{% for dayone in inizio %}
    {% if giorno == dayone.inizio|date:"d" %}
        <div class="integrazione">
            <div>
                <img src="{% static 'img/integratori.svg' %}" class="img-fluid">
                <h6 class="m-0">{{ dayone.integratore }}</h6>
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Can you show the for loop code also/

Comment: sorry in if not in for

Comment: I updated the code inside that for loop I have to put an if and I need the day of that date

Comment: the problem could probably be because of types, where giorno is integer and dayone.inizio|date:"d" is STRING

Comment: and how can I solve this problem?

Comment: You need to use templatetags, you can even return HTML string from that tag or use both of them to normalize types

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{% for dayone in inizio %}
    {% if giorno|slugify == dayone.inizio|date:"d" %}
        <div class="integrazione">
            <div>
                <img src="{% static 'img/integratori.svg' %}" class="img-fluid">
                <h6 class="m-0">{{ dayone.integratore }}</h6>
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).